# Passing an object from F# into a C# method which takes it as an out parameter doesn't work?

Tags: c#, f#, pass-by-reference

One of the libraries I'm using defines this in C#:

```
public ushort GetParameterSet(string name, out ParameterSet parameterSet)
```

I'm trying to call this from F#:

```
let parameterSet = new ParameterSet();
let retVal = currentPanel.GetParameterSet(name, ref parameterSet);
```

However, even though the parameterSet is set to an instance of that
class with valid data in the C# method, it does not change in F#.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
// let parameterSet = null;
let retval, parameterSet = currentPanel.GetParamterSet(name);
```

You shouldn't pass an instance as `ref` parameter, when the method expects an out parameter (which upon calling should be an unassigned reference preceded by the `out` keyword).

Comment: Wow nice... So why does fsharp have the ref keyword and allow it if it does not work that way (yours does btw)

Comment: The distinction between `ref` and `out` is purely a C# distinction that isn't visible "outside" - for example, VB doesn't have it, and will treat both C# `ref` and `out` as `ByRef`. And it is certainly fine to pass an initialized variable to an `out`-parameter - there's no requirement that the variable _must_ be unassigned, even in C#.

Comment: I knew it you *can*, I meant you *shouldn't*. But I was not aware of that this is C#-only, I thought it's a CLR thing. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Why shouldn't you? I can have a variable with some value that I have already used, and I just want to overwrite it with a new one. Passing an assigned variable to `out`-parameter is not any different from using `operator=` to assign a new value to the same variable. Both are perfectly legal, and have valid reasons. Perhaps you're confusing this with the requirement that variable passed to `ref` _must_ be initialized, while `out` does not have such limitation?

Comment: It should be noted that `out` parameters are now supported in F#. Though the magic desugar is still easiest.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, why your code doesn't work as is: `ref` doesn't have the same meaning in F# as it does in C#. In F#, `'a ref` is a *type*. It's not magical, either - it's really just a record with a single field `contents`, defined as follows:

```
type 'a ref = { mutable contents : 'a }
```

It *is not* a pointer or reference to a local variable. Thus, when you write this:

```
let x = 0
let y = ref x
```

you *do not* have variable `y` referencing `x`. Instead, you have variable `y` of type `int ref`, with the value of `contents` initialized to the value that `x` had (that is 0). You can change that:

```
y.contents <- 1
```

and this will not change the value of `x`. It will only change the value of `contents`

F# also provides some syntactic sugar for `'a ref`. Specifically, this:

```
y.contents <- y.contents + 1
```

can be written shorter as:

```
y := !y + 1
```

Thus `:=` is a shorthand for assigning to `contents`, and `!` is a shorthand for reading its value.

See [Reference Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186(VS.100).aspx) in MSDN for more information on `ref`.

Now F# has a magic cast associated with `'a ref` type, that lets you pass an instance of that type to a foreign function that expects a `byref` argument (both `ref` and `out` in C# map to `byref` in IL). In this case, if function changes the value of the argument, the value of `contents` in your `ref` instance changes accordingly. In your example, `ref parameterSet` created a new instance of `ref`, passed it to function which changed it, and then discarded it. What you should have done is this:

```
let parameterSet = ref(new ParameterSet())
let retVal = currentPanel.GetParameterSet(name, parameterSet)
...
// use parameterSet.contents as needed
```

Alternatively, you could use `let mutable` to declare a mutable local variable, and then use the magical `&` operator to pass it to the function directly as `byref`:

```
let mutable parameterSet = new ParameterSet()
let retVal = currentPanel.GetParameterSet(name, &parameterSet)
```